# Check connection of mongodb using gitlab pipeline

Tags: mongodb, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using a node image for my gitlab pipeline and inside that I am using mongo service but I am unable to connect to db. Any help please. My gitlab pipeline is like below:

```
  MONGO_HOSTNAME: mongo
  MONGO_PORT: 27017
  MONGO_PASSWORD: root
  MONGO_USER: root
  MONGO_DB: distanceMatrixDB

services:
  - mongo
connect:
  stage: test
  image: mongo
  script:
    - mongo --version
    #mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]
    - mongodb://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin;
```

---

### OUTPUT

$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
Build Info: {
"version": "4.4.1",
"gitVersion": "ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1",
"openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
"modules": [],
"allocator": "tcmalloc",
"environment": {
"distmod": "ubuntu1804",
"distarch": "x86_64",
"target_arch": "x86_64"
}
}
$ mongodb://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin;
/bin/bash: line 106: mongodb://root:root@mongo:27017/distanceMatrixDB?authSource=admin: No such file or directory

Comment: How is your gitlab runner configured? Until recent version of gitlab kubernetes executor [was exposing all services on localhost](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html), and not domain names.

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind - maybe mongo is only starting up when you are trying to access it. So you can leverage [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) with certain timeout to run your application only when it's ready.